Android SDK older version 34.0.0
I want to download Android SDK version 34.0.0. I've searched everywhere but couldn't find any. Can someone help me out on finding where can i possibly find this SDK version?
I want to set up my app in IntelliJ IDEA. without this version, I can't run this app.

You should use the Android SDK Manager to download and manage various versions of Android SDKs (you could have downloaded several versions in parallel).
When you have Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA with the Android plugin, you find it in the "Android" submenu of the "Tools" menu, or you could download the commandline version sdkmanager that is included in the commandline tools that you can download from https://developer.android.com/studio.

thank you so much for the help. but in SDK manager menu, it doesn't show up the SDK version of 34.0.0.  it only shows the version 35 API.

search the column "API level" and install the "Android xy" version that corresponds with the wanted API level. This will install the correct SDK along with other parts needed.
